# Border disappears after re-render outside the current viewscope

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: Border issues]

I have expand/collapse functionality on a webpage, rendered with react. When the dom changes after doing an expand or collapse, and scrolling the opposite way (scrolling to something that is outside the current viewscope) the borders seems to suddenly disappear on some of the rows. Most of them looks like they should, but this weird behaviour happens a bit randomly. If i inspect the css, and does a minor change on it (not related to the border), then the border comes back in the viewscope. Scrolling outside the viewscope again will reproduce the same behaviour.

This happens both in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle please?

Comment: i can try, i need to extract the parts needed to reproduce it

Comment: seemed to be some weird behaviour when adding a <ul></li> with <div class="row"> and some content inside the <tr><td colSpan="7"> that was expanding. Using foundation, so maybe that caused it, i removed the divs with class row, and that solved it